# How to redirect a file to a custom cdn script?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a redirect for the following example:

http://example.com/contents/2018/01/image.png
to
http://cdn.example.com/cdn.php?url=contents/2018/01/image.png

Many thanks!

Comment: How do you want to do that?
apache mod-rewrite?
in php?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about apache mod-rewrite

Comment: And I would like to use a htaccess file in the root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this through mod-rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/contents/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://cdn.example.com/cdn.php?url=contents/$1/$2/$3 [R=301,L]
```